# Парсинг сайта Юла

Tags: python, html

Парсил сайт юла на языке python через requests и столкнулся с проблемой.
Если зайти на любое объявление, то там будут описание, местоположение и т.д.
Хотел их спарсить, но не получилось.
Посмотрел исходный код страницы, в нём тег div с id="app" пустой (в нём была вся нужная информация если смотреть через Elements).
Что нужно сделать, чтобы достать данные?
P.s.
Обнаружил, что при использовании selenium удаётся парсить нужные данные.
Наверно, нужные данные приходят только после перехода по ссылке и прогрузки.
Но возможно ли спарсить данные через requests?

Comment: В браузерных инструментах разработчика открыть мониторинг сети (Network), там посмотреть, откуда конкретно скачиваются нужные данные, и уже потом повторить то же самое в requests. Смотреть в Elements абсолютно бессмысленно

Comment: Нужные данные появляются сразу после перехода по ссылке

Comment: Это никак не противоречит тому что я написал, смотрите Network

Comment: А можете посоветовать какой-нибудь сайт, чтобы почитать и лучше понять про Network

Answer (score 0):

Ищи блок в котором текст равен "Местоположение" или "Описание", ну и соответсвенно бери следующий идущий за ним блок.
Удобно разбирать html с помощью bs4

Comment: Проблема в том, что эти блоки находятся в теге <div id="app">, который в исходном коде пустой

Comment: Ну это может говорить, о том что страница прогружается динамически. Используй selenium для таких задач

Comment: А requests вообще никак не получиться?

Comment: Увы, но нет. Страница прогружается с исползование js и ajax. Requests получает только html который выплёвывает сервер, а дорисовку содержимого выполняет непосредственно браузер, поэтому requests для решения такой задачи неуместен

Comment: И отправление запросов на сервер тоже не поможет?

Comment: @Ivan поможет, конечно... ищите, откуда приходят ваши данные